# How to set xlim and ylim in summaryPlot?

Tags: r, plot, openair

I would like to know if I can set the xlim and ylim in summaryPlot-Openair. In the image I have mar, abr and may. But what about if I want to set to March, April and May. In the ylim I would like to set MP2.5 instead of PM2.5. Is it possible? Also, I would like to change the english words (missing, mean...) to spanish. I already use Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Spanish"), but it didn´t work.

[image: example summaryPlot]